# How to debug optimized C++ code in visual studio

Tags: c++, debugging

I want to check my optimized C++ code(assembly language) in visual studio, but I can't.

I try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-optimized-code?view=vs-2022), but "cl : command line error D8016: '/O2' and '/RTC1' command-line options are incompatible" error occurred.

please help me.

Comment: `/RTC1` option is never mentioned on the linked page and is indeed incompatible with optimized build.

Comment: Just turn off the RCT1 option.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't support run-time checks in release builds  or any optimization directives (they fail silently) in builds with /RTC options enabled. Looks like you tried to enable optimization in Debug profile of project.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your configuration profile and VS version, Debug config may contain /RTC (run-time checks) options by default. You shouldn't try to make a Release-with-Debug-Info out of the Debug configuration, you have to add debug information to Release config, preferably making a copy of it.

As a general rule for such cases, just trust compiler's errors and decide which option out of two incompatible must stay.